# converting multi user login

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a user table name USERS `` user_id`, `username`, `user_type`, `password `` and I also create a login form it's working well. But I want to create a SESSION by user_type, I mean when a user will be logged in from same login page they will be redirect to  different pages with SESSION ID, like "user and admin page" . I have tried with some different ways but its not working. here is my recent code how could i use user_type any help will be appreciated ! html form

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" />
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i> Sign in</button>
```

`

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
header('location: http://localhost/stock/dashboard.php');   
}

$errors = array();

if($_POST) {        

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if(empty($username) || empty($password)) {
    if($username == "") {
        $errors[] = "Username is required";
    } 
    if($password == "") {
    $errors[] = "Password is required";
    }
} else {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
    $result = $connect->query($sql);
    if($result->num_rows == 1) {
        $password = md5($password);
        // exists
        $mainSql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
        $mainResult = $connect->query($mainSql);

        if($mainResult->num_rows == 1) {
    $value = $mainResult->fetch_assoc();
    $user_id = $value['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['userId'] = $user_id;
    header('location: 
    http://localhost/stock/dashboard.php'); 
    } else{$errors[] = "Incorrect username/password combination";
        } 
    } else {        
    $errors[] = "Username doesnot exists";      
    } // /else
} // /else not empty username // password

} // /if $_POST
?>`
```

Comment: There's not even any approach redirecting on `user_type`.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone this one is my old script and it's working i want to add here new condition by user_type but i can't understand , how and where could i  implement ...!!

Comment: I'm unclear what you are trying to do ... "But i want to create a SESSION by user_type"  means what - can you explain.    Is your objective to allow different people login and get different software features ?  Eg Accounts Staff get Accounting Menu, Engineering Get Engineers Menu etc ?   If that is the case the session is misleading - not how I'd approach that. More Info please

Comment: @user1302114 i am sorry i had some explanation problem, yes you are right . i want that my objective to allow different people login and get different software features . Eg Accounts Staff get Accounting Menu, Engineering Get Engineers Menu etc . How can i do that ? need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a full answer but possibly enough for you to do the rest. If not, I'm happy to help more.
The code would fit into your existing code after the user login has been verified.

```
  switch ($usergroup)
  {
    case "ACCOUNTS":
        $rootfile = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."accounts.html.php";
    break;

    case "ENGINEERS":
        $rootfile = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."engineers.html.php";
    break;
  }
  if (file_exists($rootfile))
  {
    include $rootfile;
  }
  else 
  {
    echo "<br> ROOT FILE DOES NOT EXIST <br>";
  }
```

You would have to get the UserGroup (or UserType) in a variable before this code.

ADDED LATER

You have already stored a user id reference in the session with

```
$_SESSION['userId'] = $user_id;
```

That should only be set when the user has logged in correctly
On later pages (Eg the included file for Accounts or Engineers) you may wish to first check they are already logged in
You can do this with a line like this

```
$user_was = $_SESSION['userId'];
```

Then if $user_was = "" or does not exist - the user has not logged in

Comment: if i have get full one it will be more easy for me . I am really confused about this Session matters . If you make a full answer for me . it will be your kindness according to this script . coz i already made few features according to this script . Thanks a lot

Comment: Thats not how this works - this is a forum for getting help, you have to do a lot of work yourself.  The session can be confusing but it is just a method of allowing your code to keep track of certain variables so that the user doesn't have to repeatedly do things.Your browser agrees a session id with the web server when it first gets to any website - then it remembers that until you close the browser. So if I login on page 1 your php code knows that when I get to page 2 - if you store something in the session to let it know

Comment: If you do not store in the session that a user has logged in, it will have no way of knowing when that user moves on to the next page and would have to ask him/her again to login. So in your case what you next have to do is store some kind of indicator in the session that a successful login has happened for the user of the session that called your php file.

Comment: @ user1302114 Thanks a lot i solved it with elseif condition and now it's working !

Comment: i have got another problem !! i tried to retrieve user data by SESSION but problem is Call to a member function fetch_array()....SCRIPT  if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])){$userId=$_SESSION['userId'];
$selectUsers=" SELECT * users WHERE user_id= $userId";
$userQuery = $connect->query($selectUsers); while($userrow = $userQuery->fetch_array()) { }

Comment: You need from in your query "$selectUsers = "SELECT * from users WHERE...."

Comment: OMG i am sorry man for bothering you i just don't notice it . Thanks a lot .

Comment: No worries - we all have those moments

Comment: i have a dropdown menu and i wrote this for that if id="brandName<?php echo $x; ?>" onchange="getBrandData()" > set then id="productName <?php echo $x; ?>" witll be active ajax code is function getBrandData() {
 if (row){
  var brandId = $("#brandName" + row).val();
  if (brandId== ""){
    $("productName" + row).val("");
  }else { $.ajax({url: "php_action/drop.php",
 type: "post",
data: { brandId: brandId },dataType: "json",success: function(response) { $("#productName" + row).val(response.productName);}});} } but it's not working plz help very important for my project

Comment: PHP if (isset($_POST["brandId"])){ 
$brand =$_GET["brandId"];
$productSql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE brand_id= $brandId";
$productData = $connect->query($productSql);

while($row = $productData->fetch_array()) {            
echo "<option value='".$row['product_id']."' id='changeProduct".$row['product_id']."' ".$selected." >".$row['product_name']."</option>";
}     
}
$connect->close();
echo json_encode($row);

Comment: It's hard to follow code in a comment, if you post this as a new question and then post a link to that new question in here as a comment - I'll take a look

Comment: @ user1302114 i don't have enough question limit !!! can i have your mail or something ? or you can send me a mail it's effety@gmail.com

Comment: email sent - check your junk folder

Comment: I didn't get mail from any personal email. no inbox no junk .. (:  #user1302114

Comment: well it was from my gmail account - so it'll get there - but I'll send it again  subject user1302114

Comment: @user1302114 I have got a problem all program is working on localhost ! But when i am uploading to online server , Some feature is not working !!! I used PDO version here is the link chatworld.xyz user = amit pass =12345 Go to deposit and press deposit setup it's giving error text but it's working on localhost !! my mail id is effety@gmail.com please send me a mail !

Comment: @effetty-hassan-mukul I'm not seeing "Deposit Setup" as an option ... sent screen grab in email

Comment: Give me your mail address please if you have no problem with it !

Comment: #Knee_Colas  Give me your mail address